# FFPLAY DASH error on start

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, dash

i'll trying to play a DASH streaming on Google Media CDN with ffplay but i have this error:

```
Failed to parse format-tag beginning with %010d$.m4s. Expected either a closing '$' character or a format-string like '%0[width]d', where width must be a single digit

[https @ 0x7f3fa4010c40] HTTP error 404 Not Found sq=    0B f=0/0   

[dash @ 0x7f3fa4000cc0] Failed to open fragment of playlist
```

is DASH manifest not correct?

"SegmentTemplate timescale="1000000" initialization="mux_video/segment-initialization_segment_0000000034.m4s" **media="mux_video/segment-$Number%010d$.m4s"** startNumber="17047" presentationTimeOffset="1065000"

thanks in advance